# solve a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Solve the system of $n$ equations and $n$ unknowns which the equations are $\left (L_{i}  \right ): x_{i}-x_{i+1}=1$ for $i=1,2,....,n-1$ and $\left (L_{n}  \right ):x_{n}=1$

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_{i} - x_{i+1}=1\\ 
x_{n}=1
\end{matrix}\right.$

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_{1} - x_{2}=1\\ 
x_{n}=1
\end{matrix}\right.$

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_{2} - x_{3}=1\\ 
x_{n}=1
\end{matrix}\right.$

$\vdots $

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_{n-1} - x_{n}=1\\ 
x_{n}=1
\end{matrix}\right.$

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_{n-1} =2\\ 
x_{n}=1
\end{matrix}\right.$

solution is $\left ( 2;1 \right )$

is it correct guys ? Thanks for looking

Comment: You are supposed to find a solution $\forall$ $x_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, we will also have $$x_{n-2}-x_{n-1} = 1\Rightarrow x_{n-2} = 3$$Similarly $$x_{n-3}-x_{n-2} =1 \Rightarrow x_{n-3}=4$$ $$\vdots$$ $$ x_1-x_2 =1\Rightarrow x_1 = n $$ as we are supposed to find a solution for all $i $.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Riiiiiiiiight how could i forget about it . Thanks man it helps a lot .

Comment: we can also say that the sum of solutions is $(n+1;n)$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}^{\ast }$